# ER Diagrams - Can someone please explain modality?

Tags: sql, mariadb, entity-relationship, erd, modality

ER Diagrams - Can someone please explain modality?

[image: Modality - one at both ends]

Above: If there is a module it must belong to a course. And if there is a course we'd really like there to be a module. But is the diagram correct?

The foreign key constraint enforces that if a module exists in the child table then there will be a course in the parent table. But there is no constraint the other way, and obviously you have to create one record before the other.

So, is this more correct (below)?

[image: Modality - one at one end, zero at the other]

Or does modality zero mean the FK can be null?

Answer (score 1):

1. The first diagram is correct
2. No the "O" on the right only mean you allow to have a course with no modules, it's a 0-n relation.

So the first one mean 1-n relation , what you want, but you can't enforce 1-n more than 0-n in SQL. Using "|<" is for documentation, and code implementation, and not for SQL constraint.

The meaning of your convention:
[image: ERD legend]

Side note: I prefer the UML "0-n" notation which is more explicit, here would be the result in plantUML: (use planttext.com for the render)
[image]

```
@startuml
title Relationships - Class Diagram
class Courses
class Modules
Courses "1" *-up- "1-n" Modules: Composition
@enduml
```

Comment: [This site](https://www.calebcurry.com/cardinality-and-modality/) suggests "Modality illustrates whether a column is null or not null".

Comment: "If there is a module it must belong to a course" that would mean the first diagram is correct as the FK could not be null.

Comment: @user3121215 A nullable FK means a 0-1 relation, the other side is always 0-n in SQL, as I explained.

Comment: [This site](https://www.calebcurry.com/cardinality-and-modality/) suggests otherwise.

Comment: @user312518 you already suggest this site, which is good, and, sorry, but you didn't seem to understand, and don't state what you claim

Comment: "No the "O" on the right only mean you allow to have no modules," - I don't think that is correct. You could have modules that did not belong to a course if the modality was zero. 

Also, the question was about ER Diagrams not UML.

Comment: @user312518 OK, I proposed UML, I will improve my answer, and I suggest you to improve your own answer to add theses elements.